# What is the value of $AD+CD$ where $ABC$ is an isosceles triangle, $D$ bisects angle $ACB, BC = 2017$ unit?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

> $ABC$ is an isosceles ($AB = AC$) and $\angle A = 100^{\circ}$. An point $D$ is on $AB$ so that $CD$ angle bisector $\angle ACB$. If $BC= 2017$ then calculate $AD+CD$.

Source: [Bangladesh Math Olympiad 2017 junior category](https://www.matholympiad.org.bd/).

Comment: all angles are known: do you know sines law ?

Comment: Thanks I've just learned that. But I am confused that how am I supposed to figure it out without calculator. (Sine 40 degree) Could you please help me?

Comment: didn't get through the solution, but probably you are supposed to use the fact that $40 = 100-60$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $E$ be on $BC$ so $CE = CD$. Then $\angle DEC = 80^{\circ}$ so $CADE$ is cyclic, so we have by the power of the point with respect to $B$: $$a\cdot (a-d) = b\cdot (b-x)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)$$

[image]

By angle bisector theorem we have $${b-x\over x} = {a\over b}\implies b(b-x)= ax\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(2)$$

By (1) and (2) we have $$a(a-d)= ax \implies a-d= x$$

Since we are searching for $d+x = a= 2017$ we are done.